# Unable to get Ripple session info. Exception: contentp-body

Tags: visual-studio-cordova, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio 2015 CTP 5

Created a blank Apache Cordova Project. No files changed. 
File > New Project > JavaScript > Apache Cordova Apps

Published
Debug  Android  Ripple - Nexus (Galaxy)

I get the following error in Output Debug.

*--------------------------------*

*Unable to get launched browser process for Ripple.*

*Unable to get Ripple session info. Exception: Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.*

Note:  Publishing with Ripple is currently not working, but has worked intermittently in the past.

Comment: Start Chrome with Ripple plugin installed  before running the app.  Also reinstalling Node.js (and cleaning up npm folders in user profile folder) helps sometimes. Though it doesn't always work. VS2015 is very unstable for now.

Comment: Drop3, followed your suggestions (Start Chrome, re-install Node,js) but it did not work.  I repaired Visual Studio 2015 CTP5 using Add Remove Programs and re-installed Chrome.  That didn't work either.  After adding, removing, modifying, etc. I created a new Cordova Project. File > New Project > JavaScript > Apache Cordova Apps  When I published Nexus (Galaxy) it worked.  Unfortunately, when I try to open the original Cordova Project I am still unable to debug > Android > Ripple Nexus (Galaxy).  I'll do a diff on the two projects to see what the problem is.

Comment: I believe I found the problem.  The projects .sln had missing information in the GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution. The Fix = In file *.sln, Delete GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution and all the objects.  Save the *.sln file and open the project in VS.  VS will rewrite the GlobalSection values and fix the problem.  I don't know what caused the problem.  I still get "Unable to get Ripple session info. Exception: Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.", but at least the code runs in the browser.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. There is a similar problem with *.suo files being corrupted for Android native projects and solutions. But in this case, whole IDE hangs on startup. Deleting this file solves the problem. Random crashes are also not uncommon. I just hope they'll fix those problems before release.

Comment: Drop,  I'm glad I'm not the only one having these problems.  2015 preview seemed much more stable that CTP 5.  Every time I run into a problem I think it's something I did wrong when in actuality it's a bug in 2015. Example: Using gulp.js and Task Runner Explorer.  Gulp file should be recognized and tasks displayed in TRX. Bug in 2015 CTP 5 prevents Gulp from working.  However, Bower works.  UGH!

Answer (score 5):

The Fix = In file *.sln, Delete GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution and all the objects. Save the *.sln file and open the project in VS. VS will rewrite the GlobalSection values and fix the problem. I don't know what caused the problem.  Applies to VS2015 CTP 5.

Comment: Where you opening project created using previous version of Visual Studio Cordova tools or was it a new project. I am wondering what might have caused GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution to have values which caused this issue.

Comment: Tnis worked for me, both for ripple and for the microsoft VS emulator. Thanks!

Comment: I have been searching all day for a solution. My setup is running on a windows 2012 server vm and i suspected that to be the culprit.  This was a 5 second fix I found in 6 hrs haha

Comment: This answer was similar, and it worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30368979/79444

Comment: The other answer given by @veljkoz also worked for me: Delete the .suo file.

Comment: personally i'm still having this issue on one particular machine.  corp issued image installed via pxe boot.  going to flatten it back to a straight MSDN install and see if that resolved it.  frustrated myself.

Comment: Works for : "Unable to get Ripple session info. Exception: Unable to connect to the remote server. Please close all instances of Chrome and try again."