# Unable to get Ripple session info

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova, ripple

I created an Ionic (Apache Cordova) app using Visual Studio 2015 RC. I created it in its own solution file, and I can run it using Ripple.

Now I want to move the files into the same folder as my server application, so I copied the project folder and added the project to the other solution.
If I now try to run the project using Ripple I get this error:

> Unable to get Ripple session info. Exception: Unable to connect to the
>   remote server. Please close all instances of Chrome and try again.

How can I get Ripple running again?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The root of this problem appears to be in the project's [Solution Options File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165909.aspx).

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Delete the `.suo` file

When the `.suo` file is missing, it is created when Visual Studio closes, so you must close first.

You will lose user preferences such as start-up project and current pages, but nothing I would regard as significant.

I am using VS2015 and I found the file in a sub-folder named `.vs/MyProject/v14`. Previous versions of Visual Studio put the file in the same folder as the .sln file.

NB it is a "hidden" file

Reference:
[The evil .suo file](http://briannoyes.net/2008/05/10/the-evil-suo-file-fighting-and-winning-with-visual-studio/)

Comment: This worked for me for VS2015 RTM. I owe you a beer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I came across this error recently - I found that the Debug config was defaulting to "Any CPU" and I got Ripple working again by switching it to "Android" (and "Galaxy tablet"). I'm not sure if this is too simple a fix but it worked for me - note that I didn't have VS2015 running in administrator mode (or remove the .suo) file.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is the exact cause, but it's worth to try the following:
1. Delete the solution file .sln.
2. Open your cordova project file.
3. Save the new created solution and add server app project.

Visual studio will help you to rebuild the .sln file during above steps.

Answer (score 0):

For users (like me) for whom this solution does not work: I resolved the below error on Windows 7:

> Unable to get Ripple session info. Exception: Unable to connect to the
>   remote server. Please close all instances of Chrome and try again

By simply running VS2015RC as an administrator.